# void in Chrome console - strange SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Purely a curiosity, but why does Chrome (31) raise `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` when executing the (invalid) statement `void` from the JS console?

I understand that the JS engine should raise a syntax error - `void` requires an argument. I don't understand what a `}` has to do with it.

The same invalid statement, when executed from the URL bar with `javascript:void` or in a web page, results in a more sensible `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.

Comment: It probably has to do with the way the console works internally. One of the functions on  the stack when that error is generated is something called "evaluateAndWrap", which makes me think that the stuff you type in is augmented with some extra text before evaluation, and that part of that is a pair of enclosing curly braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run a `debugger;` statement in the console, you'll see:

[image]

Your code is wrapped inside of `with(console ...)` block. The unexpected `}` is the one that closes the block. Mentally replace the `debugger;` with a `void` with no arguments, and you can see how you'd get that error.